# Loading co-dependent groovy classes in Java

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to figure out how to load two co-dependent Groovy scripts in java at runtime.  If I have two groovy scripts like:

#### A.groovy

```
import B

class A {
  A() {
    B b = new B()
  }
}
```

#### B.groovy

```
import A

class B {
  B() {
    A a = new A()
  }
}
```

I would like to load them as java classes, but when I run:

```
ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
loader.parseClass(new File("A.groovy"));
```

I get the error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
A.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class B
@ line 1, column 1.
import B
```

I certainly understand the reason for the error, but is there any way to load these classes at runtime despite their co-dependency?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroovyClassLoader must be enabled to find B.groovy on the classpath. Normally that means you change the classpath of you application to include the root of the scripts. Since there is no package here for the scripts and since you use new File("A.groovy"), I would assume that it is here the current directory.

If you don't want to change the classpath of the application, you can also call addURL to add the path containing the scripts.

One more thing to mention.... parseClass will always create a newly parsed class. You might want to try a standard loadClass call instead to avoid compiling the file multiple times. But of course that works only after you fixed the lookup for GroovyClassLoader, because using loadClass, GroovyClassLoader will also have to look for A.groovy in the same manner it does have to look for B.groovy

Comment: Cool, that worked, thanks.  I added the folder to the classpath and then just called loadClass("A").